# How to use multiple versions at the same time in an Apigility app with Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, version, dbconnection, laminas-api-tools

Context first: [Apigility](https://apigility.org/) driven application based on [Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/). In the first version (`V1`) I was using the [`ZfcBase`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase) [`DbMapper`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase/blob/master/src/ZfcBase/Mapper/AbstractDbMapper.php) for the model layer. Now I'm implementing the `V2` with [Doctrine 2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) as ORM.

Apigility provides an easy switching between versions and every version can use its own DB adapter:

**`/config/autoload/global.php`** / **`/config/autoload/local.php`**

```
<?php
return array(
    ...
    'db' => array(
        'adapters' => array(
            'DB\\myproject_v1' => array(
                // settings (driver, hostname, database, driver_options)
                // credentials (username, password)
                ...
            ),
            'DB\\myproject_v2' => array(
                // settings (driver, hostname, database, driver_options)
                // credentials (username, password)
                ...
            ),
        ),
    ),
    ...
);
```

So, to use another version as default with another database behind it only the URL needs to be changed:

```
myproject.tld/my-endpoint    <-- version set to default
myproject.tld/v1/my-endpoint <-- version 1
myproject.tld/v2/my-endpoint <-- version 2
```

I want to add Doctrine 2 to my application, so I extended my `local.php` like [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/README.md#connection-settings) shown:

```
<?php
return array(
    ...
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    // settings (host, port, dbname)
                    // credentials (user, password)
                    ...
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    ...
);
```

It's working, but now I don't have the flexibility for switching between the versions / for using different versions with different databases behind them. My adapter settings are getting overridden by the doctrine connection configs or just ignored.

**How to combine Doctrine with the versioning flexibility of Apigility? How to configure the DB connection in an Apigility application with Doctrine and stay able to switch between the verions / to use multiple versions at the same time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following section of your config:

```
[
    'db'=>[
        'adapters' => [
            'DB\\myproject_v1' => [],
            'DB\\myproject_v2' => [],
        ]
    ]
]
```

configures an abstract factory that registers the service names `DB\\myproject_v1` and `DB\\myproject_v2` with db adapter instances.

It is the part of the configuration below that actually assigns the adapter to your DB connected resource:

```
'db-connected' => array(
    'YourDBConnectedResource' => array(
        'adapter_name'     => 'DB\\myproject_v1',
    ),
),
```

Doctrine provides its own abstract factory and configuration, so to make Apigility work with Doctrine as your database adapter, you just have to tweak the configuration a bit. First, lets add a second connection to your doctrine config to help illustrate the change.

```
return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            'orm_default' => [ // you don't have to use orm_default, you can arbitrarily name this version1
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => [
                    // settings (host, port, dbname)
                    // credentials (user, password)

                ],
            ],
            'version2' => [
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => [
                    // settings (host, port, dbname)
                    // credentials (user, password)
                ],
            ],            
        ],
    ],
];
```

Now, your DB adapter names are `doctrine.connection.orm_default` and `doctrine.connection.version2`. So you substitute those in your db-connected configuration block.

```
'db-connected' => [
    'My\\Endpoint\\V1\\Rest\\MyResource' => [
        'adapter_name'     => 'doctrine.connection.orm_default',
    ],
    'My\\Endpoint\\V2\\Rest\\MyResource' => [
        'adapter_name'     => 'doctrine.connection.version2',
    ],
],
```